# MySQL export - import of a log table / partial synchronization (full export, import in an existing table)

Tags: mysql, synchronization, data-synchronization

We've got a MySQL database that's filling up with log-entries. These log entries are essential for our data-crunching, but the log table is getting out of hand. Querying it slows down our site, so we are taking action.

We are setting up a separate log-database-server which will contain all log-entries we have generated so far. That means we can delete all log history from our live server. Each week we want to export the generated log entries from our production-server to our log-server. Preferably we want to automate that.

In my mind the synchronize option in MySQL will not work, since it would result in nearly emptying the log table on the log-database to keep it in sync with production.

Can you help us on how we can set this up and how we can automate this process?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

This use case is one of the reasons people consider using the Cassandra product. I am dumping all my logs into a cassandra cluster for processing. It allows you to do a lot more than you can do with MySQL.

```
http://cassandra.apache.org
```

In my experience, using Cassandra to hold the log data has made so many things much more productive.